# $(\nabla - \vec{g}) \cdot \vec{f}(r,\theta)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Knowing $\vec{g}$, how can above equation be solved for $f$? There is a symmetry in $\phi$ in spherical coordinate, so the equation is a 2D equation. Also, $\vec{g}$ is a complete curl. Could anyone please help me?

more information $\vec{f}$ could be written as $\nabla h(r,\theta)$.
Boundary condition:

$\vec{f}_r=0$ at infinity. $f_r(r=1)= - A$

which $A$ is a constant.

If more is needed:

$g_\theta(r,\theta) = \sin \theta (1-\frac{\sin \theta }{2 r^2})-\frac{\alpha \sin ^2 \theta \cos \theta}{r^4}$

$g_r(r,\theta) = -\cos \theta (1-\frac{1}{ r^3})+\frac{3\alpha}{2r^2}(\frac{1}{r^2}-1)(\cos^2 \theta-\frac{1}{3})$

Comment: You mean $\vec g = \nabla \times \vec h$ for some $\vec h$?

Comment: I mean I know functionality of $g(r,\theta)$ in spherical coordinate, and I know that $\nabla \cdot \vec{g}=0$ @RobertLewis

Comment: I have edited my comment @RobertLewis

Comment: I don't know the notation  you used on $\vec g$.  You mean $\nabla \cdot g = 0$?

Comment: Yes, exactly @RobertLewis

Comment: I see, you typed "\div g" and got $\div g$.  DIvergence in $\LaTeX$ is $\nabla \cdot$.

Comment: Do you know how can I find f? @RobertLewis

Comment: Not sure.  Thinking about it.  I've got to work this afternoon so I may not get back to you for a few hours.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think without explicit expression for $\vec {g} \cdot \vec {f} $ you are left with trivial solutions for example $ f=0$

Take any continuously differentiable vector field $\vec{f}(r,\theta)$ with a compact support then by Helmholtz decomposition :

$ f= \nabla h + \nabla $ x $ z $

$\nabla^2 h= \vec {g} \cdot \vec {f} $ which is Poisson equation and solution exists given the conditions we have on $\vec {g}  $ and $\vec {f}  $

Comment: I think it can not be solve by knowing boundary conditions. I added the boundary condition and $g$ in the question. Do you know how can it be solve?